# Why does robot_model fail in rosinstall

Tags: ros, robot-model, rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I get the following when rosinstall hits the robot_model line in .rosinstall:

```
- hg: {local-name: robot_model, uri: 'https://kforge.ros.org/robotmodel/robot_model',
    version: robot_model-1.4.0}
```

This despite having Mercurial installed via macports and having several other hg lines in my .rosinstall which install fine. What's going on?

```
Installing https://kforge.ros.org/robotmodel/robot_model robot_model-1.4.0 to /Users/my_name/ros/robot_model
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/rosinstall", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('rosinstall==0.5.16', 'rosinstall')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 442, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 1167, in run_script
    exec script_code in namespace, namespace
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/rosinstall-0.5.16-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 556, in <module>
    
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/rosinstall-0.5.16-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 534, in rosinstall_main
    
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/rosinstall-0.5.16-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 276, in execute_install
    
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/rosinstall-0.5.16-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 115, in install
    
AttributeError: VCSClient instance has no attribute 'type'
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9493/why-does-robot_model-fail-in-rosinstall/) by [Eponymous](https://answers.ros.org/users/196/eponymous/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2011-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking closer the line which is failing(rosinstall:115) reads: "Failed to detect %s presence at %s."%(self.vcsc.type, self.path"  which suggests that it is finding the path exists already but it does not detect a mercurial checkout in the place.

I suggest deleting that path and running it again.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eponymous](https://answers.ros.org/users/196/eponymous/) on 2011-03-20**:
That did it, and by "that" I mean that I deleted the robot_model path and re-ran rosinstall. Not quite sure what went wrong there.